# React Intl Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-intl, react-hooks-testing-library

I have used latest version of React-intl(^5.20.2). Trying to achieve Enzyme Unit testing in React hook component. but throwing this error "[React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object.  needs to exist in the component ancestry." on UseIntl() inside functional component while running tests

```
{intl.formatMessage({ id: "Welcome" })}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the component under test with the `IntlProvider` component. You can do this by creating a wrapper to pass in the options with the `render` utility.

[Wrapper](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#wrapper)

> Pass a React Component as the `wrapper` option to have it rendered
> around the inner element. This is most useful for creating reusable
> custom render functions for common data providers.

Example:

```
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';

export const IntlWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <IntlProvider locale="en">{children}</IntlProvider>
);
```

Test code

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { IntlWrapper } from '../path/to/testUtils';

...

render(
  <ComponentUnderTest />,
  {
    wrapper: IntlWrapper,
  },
);
```

Comment: "No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(ui: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>, options: RenderOptions<typeof import>" is throwing while using wrapper after component

Comment: @Vindhiya It should work, but you can also just directly wrap the component  being tested with the `IntlProvider` component too.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in my case it was due to SSR.

In addition of the "locale" Provider which allow language switching.

I've added to my `_document.jsx` a Provider which get the locale from the router.

```
class MyDocument extends Document<TDocumentInitialProps> {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext): Promise<TDocumentInitialProps> {
        const messages = (await importMessages(ctx.locale)) as Record<string, string> | Record<string, MessageFormatElement[]>;

        return {
            locale: ctx.locale,
            messages,
        };
    }

    render(): JSX.Element {
        const { locale, messages } = this.props;

        return (
        <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
            <Html lang={locale}>
            <Head>
                <link rel="icon" href="/images/layout/favicon.png" />
            </Head>
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
            </Html>
        </IntlProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```